# Fetching Object value in mongodb through query

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I am making a chat app through socket.io in Android through Node.js . I want to store history of message and username which I have already stored successfully in mongodb but I want to fetch message:Object values here.. can someone please help me in writing query.

This query results in the output which you can see in the image.

```
    messagesCollection.find().toArray().then(function (docs){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(docs))
```

I want to retrieve "message" & "senderNickname" value through query. Replies are highly appreciated.

[image: Click here for Mongodb collection values]

Comment: This is my initial query

 let  message = {"message":messageContent, "senderNickname":senderNickname}

     
    
 messagesCollection.insertOne({message},function(err, res){
     console.log('Inserted a document into the messageCollection');
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass projection operators in a query,

```
messagesCollection.find({},{_id: 0, "message.message":1,"message.senderNickname":1})
.toArray().then(function (docs){console.log(JSON.stringify(docs))});
```

make `_id: 1` if you want object id as well for each record.

Comment: Thanks ... I am trying to do that way